# ScheduledExecutorService does not execute if it has moved from the main activity

Tags: android, scheduledexecutorservice

I have the code below which is in ONCreate() method of the main activity and works fine. After  moving to the next activity (B) which is a list view and then to activity (C ) which is the row selected from the listview and goes to sleep then the ScheduledExecutorService started in the main activity is not executing anymore .

Why is it not executing and how do I fix it?
I am noob in Android .Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance .Really appreciate the help.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable(){

                public void run() {


    //play audio file

    mp3.start();

                }

            }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Use Alarm Manager instead of ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: but do I have to use service along with it ?

Comment: it depends on nature of task... check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766912/android-background-service-and-alarmmanager

Comment: yes something similar .But will the alarm manager still keep running even if the app in closed or forced to stop from settings ? By the way thanks for your time .

Comment: np with my time , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859489/android-running-a-background-task-using-alarmmanager check this... 
one friendly suggestion , increase your googling :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744933/how-to-restart-service-using-intentservice-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527581/how-to-ensure-alarmmanager-survives-phone-restart-and-application-kill

Comment: so by default the service will stop if the app is killed or force closed right ? this question has been troubling me for a long time .

Comment: I want it to closed and begin again when the user starts the application .

Comment: if you only want it to start when user starts the application you can start the bind the service on oncreate of your app , and unbind ... do you want the service only to run while the app is running or continue running when app is no longer in foreground ? if you want the app to continue running then use startservice with STICKY flag

Comment: it should run only till the app is running and stop if app is killed or closed .Thats the current requirement .

Comment: Then use simple AlarmManager, no need of service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643850/android-alarm-is-cancelled-after-closing-the-application

Comment: Thanks baboo .Will check it out and let you know how it goes.Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Another query I have Baboo Whats the difference between AlarmManager vs ScheduledExecutorService .Or Pros and cons. PLease Help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558694/difference-between-alarmmanager-and-scheduledexecutorservice

Comment: Hi Baboo thanks for the link.I checked it and noticed that I need to use AlarmManager which works like a ScheduledExecutorService(Sorry for the confusion).In other words ScheduledExecutorService works till app is running and not sleeping ,but it does not manage memory . I want it to run when its not sleeping and only if the app is running in the background . How do I do the same wit Alarm Manager ? I am looking in the youtube tutorial for alarm manager but I did not find it good .Please suggest me something to resolve my query.

Comment: I am currently using ScheduledExecutorService in mu app and would like to implement alarmManage in its place .Thanks again for your time.

Comment: with the app running and the set sleeping learn to use alarm manager with WAKELOCK...  i will search for a tutorial and post it .. but u do the same

Comment: Thank You Sir.Thats very generous of you. I am doing the same right now. I got a tutorial on streaming music with service .I am checking how service is used but so far I dont think its required in my case. Case1) check server for new messages in background using asynctask with ScheduledExecutorService and case2) update user location in background I am using ScheduledExecutorService and asynctask .I will be replacing AlarmManager in its place. I dont thinh service is required.What do you think ? Thanks for cooperating and leading me through confusion and doubt.

Comment: Please put your answer as answer so that I can accept it.Also I dont have enough points to chat.Thanks Again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24501/discussion-between-james-patrick-and-baboo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to cater  the app running and the set sleeping scenario look in to using alarm manager with WAKELOCK... 
example : http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/  and 
[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Comment: try the second link i have posted in answer.. that would be most helpfull

Comment: Great .I have accepted your answer .I will be implementing each answer you suggested and get back to you through the same question if I hit any bump.Is it Okay with you ?

Comment: Thanks will get back to you soon with the results.